# How to detect different layers in an image in Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am working on an application in which I have an image, and I want to detect all the different layers of image. For example, suppose i have an interior image of a construction which contains walls, sofa, carpet, chairs, bed, etc. Now I want to detect the different layers of images like sofa, bed, chairs, walls, etc. so that I can color them separately .

Please help me .

Comment: You need to clarify your question.... What you want to do is actually crop a particular part of an image i presume....

Comment: yes I wants to crop the particular part of image and color that .

Answer (score 3):

For this, you'll have to dig into image processing:

1. A nice image processing library : [GPUImage from BradLarson](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)
2. You'll have to learn about edge-detection and derive points from that detection.
3. Once you get these points, you'll have to segregate the edges into separate closed shapes. For that you'll have to learn the implementation tactics of Convex-shapes and Concave-shapes.
4. After you have certain shapes detected on the image, you can perform colour changes into the underlying areas of image enclosed within the shapes.

However, as a reminder, this will make only approximate output, because the objects in the image can be in various lighting conditions and due to this the edge-detection may fail in capturing the true boundary of an object.

Answer (score 2):

You don't. It is not possible to write software to detect a "chair" vs a "table" in a photo/image. It is not about layers, there are only pixels in the image. You could write a tool like Photoshops magic wand, that selects colors that are near each other. But, it is not really going to actually work in any automated way because the computer cannot make decisions based on criteria like the way your mind works "seeing" a chair.